# WP7 app crashes in eventtrigger with unspecified error

Tags: windows-phone-7, xaml, eventtrigger

I'm writing an wp7 app and I have one problem with eventtrigger.
I have a listbox with this ItemTemplate:

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Name="templatePanel"  Width="200" Height="200" Margin="10">
                    <Grid.Triggers>
                        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Tap" >
                            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="templatePanel"
                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                 From="0"
                                 To="1"
                                 Duration="0:0:5"/>
                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </EventTrigger.Actions>
                        </EventTrigger>
                    </Grid.Triggers>
                <!--SOME KIND OF CONTENT-->
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
```

When I run my app it crashes with **unspecified error** with this StackTrace:

```
 at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.WrapPanel.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollContentPresenter.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.Controls.ScrollViewer.MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.MeasureOverrideNative(IntPtr element, Single inWidth, Single inHeight, Single& outWidth, Single& outHeight)
   at MS.Internal.XcpImports.FrameworkElement_MeasureOverride(FrameworkElement element, Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.PhoneApplicationFrame.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
   at System.Windows.FrameworkElement.MeasureOverride(IntPtr nativeTarget, Double inWidth, Double inHeight, Double& outWidth, Double& outHeight)
```

**BUT** if I set

```
<EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Grid.Loaded" >
```

app will **NOT** crash!

Why does it happen?
Thank in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Silverlight only supports the `Loaded` (`RoutedEvent`). Quote from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.eventtrigger.routedevent%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> In XAML you specify this as a string. In code, pass the identifier (a
>   RoutedEvent value.) The only supported value in Silverlight is
>   Loaded/FrameworkElement.LoadedEvent.